# Mapping with geom_sf(): Assigning labels to data points when you don't have distinct x,y columns in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, aesthetics

I am working to create a map in ggplot2 using the geom_sf() function. The data for the map is from a KML file (downloaded from GoogleEarth), so when I read that into R, the lat/longs for each datapoint are in a combined 'geometry' column rather than individual lat/long columns. I need to add labels for each point onto my map, but since everything is in the 'geometry' column, I do not have the proper inputs for the aes() function, when it asks for 'x' and 'y' values.

My data is currently arranged like this:

```
Name Description    Island           BeachName Density                       geometry
1  C28             St. Croix          Boiler Bay       B POINT Z (-64.57273 17.75859 0)
2  C27             St. Croix           Brown Bay       A POINT Z (-64.57583 17.75935 0)
3  C39             St. Croix Buck Island Reef NM       C POINT Z (-64.62571 17.78738 0)
4   C1             St. Croix     Sandy Point NWR       C POINT Z (-64.89964 17.67955 0)
5  C10             St. Croix       Rainbow Beach       A POINT Z (-64.88799 17.72994 0)
```

I have tried using geom_text():

```
stc_plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = stc_land, color = "grey40", fill = "grey80") +
    geom_sf(data = stcdens, aes(size = Density)) +
    geom_text(data = stcdens, aes(label = Name)) +
    labs(size = "Nesting Activities per Year") +
    scale_size_discrete(labels = c("<25", "25-100", "100-500")) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

And I get an error:

```
     Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
! geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
```

Is there a way to get the geometry column to be read out for labels? Or would I need to split that column so that the lat/longs are separate? The geometry column has worked fine for all other aspects of creating this map, its just the labeling that is giving me trouble...

Comment: The `ggsflabel` package: https://yutannihilation.github.io/ggsflabel/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You need to substitute your `ggplot2::geom_text()` for `ggplot2::geom_sf_text()` - the sf part is important.

For an example consider this plot of 3 semi random North Carolina cities (did I mention I <3 the nc.shp file?)

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)


shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333),
                     population = c("high", "medium","low")) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326) 

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shape, fill = NA) +
  geom_sf_text(data = cities, aes(label = name))
```

[image: 3 cities with labels]

Comment: Oh great, that worked! So then a follow up question I have, is how to adjust the labels so they are not directly on top of the data points? I think that I can use geom_sf_label_repel(), but R is telling me that the package required is unavailable on my version of R. There are no updates available though. Do you have any ideas on another way to accomplish that with the labels?

Comment: ggrepel is a good tool; if you need a truly fine tuning - which you sometimes do, especially in case of complicated underlying shapefile - you can consider nudge_y and nudge_y arguments. For an example in action have a look at https://community.rstudio.com/t/geom-sf-text-change-position-of-only-one-text-label/73419/6?u=jlacko